# How to use rclone to download data from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, synchronization, rclone

I have a quick question on rclone.

I am trying to download data from [tradestatistics.io](https://tradestatistics.io/accesing-the-data.html#apache-arrow-datasets), where it gives a sample code for downloading:

```
rclone sync spaces:tradestatistics/hs-rev1992-visualization hs-rev1992-visualization
```

My question is that how to access list of files in that source and can it be directly done with terminal?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you've already installed rclone (https://rclone.org/downloads/)

To configure rclone to see storage on S3, see https://rclone.org/s3/

Assuming `spaces:` is your correctly configured rclone source remote, you can list all files using terminal amnd rclone `lsl` command:

`rclone lsl spaces:tradestatistics/hs-rev1992-visualization`

where `tradestatistics` is the bucket and `hs-rev1992-visualization` is the root folder.

A more human-readable list can be done with `lsf`. It's not recursive, so add `-R`:

`rclone lsf -R spaces:`

More details at https://rclone.org/commands/rclone_lsl/ with info on other lists.

Comment: Can you look through my code below? Probably something wrong with my "rclone config"

Comment: In Mac Terminal can you run `rclone version` and let me know what comes back? My experience is configuring Google Drive, but you'll need access keys in steps 6 and 7. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/powershell/latest/userguide/pstools-appendix-sign-up.html I'm not sure about 8 and 9. What do you get when you enter this in Terminal `rclone lsl spaces:`

Comment: <rclone version> is returning: rclone v1.56.0
- os/version: darwin 11.3.1 (64 bit)
- os/kernel: 20.4.0 (x86_64)
- os/type: darwin
- os/arch: amd64
- go/version: go1.16.6
- go/linking: dynamic
- go/tags: cmount

Comment: and when I run <rclone lsl spaces>, it is just returning nothing [blank space]

Comment: It needs the `:` at the end to indicate a remote  `rclone lsl spaces:`

Comment: Did you follow https://rclone.org/s3/#digitalocean-spaces about the access keys?

Comment: thank you. I think there was a problem with MacOS compliance or firewall. Now I got direct downloadable link from the author